# Delphi, installers and Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-installer

As part of a general move to Windows 7  - where all applications should have an "installer experience", I need to create installers for all of our application suite. I have looked at [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield), but this seems extremely expensive for what it does. What install products could I look at?

The installers will need to be built unattended on our build machines, so there is a level of complexity above just being an installer builder.

**Update:**

I have looked at all of the suggestions and they look good. My plans involve pushing stuff up by [SCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager) (or something similar) to the end users. Would I need to have MSI support for that?

Comment: you can always use msiexec from within inno or nsis to perform msi related tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI installers are ideal where you have corporate installations, and a good way to create an MSI is using WiX, an XML based system. However, the files you need are complex, so I use [MSI Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/products/msi-factory/) to create the installer which handles all the usual requirements, but which then outputs the WiX files which can be built and updated by my build scripting tool [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/). This way I get the benefit of the nice UI, and of the open files tool, so no lock-in.

Comment: Why recommend something full of accidental complexity (WIX/XML/MSI) unless you know someone needs some odd little thing like unattended remote push installation.

Comment: Warren - this is just what I need - we will be pushing out the applications with an unattended remote push installation - the actual details of which will be determined later

Comment: MSI is a key part of any managed deployment, and it should be considered in any such decision. It may not be pretty, but it is what is there. WiX makes MSI more "open" to manipulation by tools, while MSI Factory gives you the UI that makes it all easy. That's why I recommend it (heck, that's why I use it!).

Comment: I have accepted this answer due to the WiX system being able to do what I want, even if it seems quite a complex setup.

Answer (score 21):

I think [Inno Setup from Jordan Russell](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) can do what you want. Oh, and it's free.

Comment: I am very fond of Inno, and it does have a command line interface so you can include it with your automated build.

Comment: I'm very happy with INNOSETUP, and find any of the MSI-based technologies to be total crap, and recommend you stay away from those, and stay with a simple tool like Inno-Setup that can (nevertheless) do many many things easily that the fat bloated MSI tools can not do.

Comment: Inno Setup also allows you to use delphi like pascal script to include any extra install logic.

Comment: @Warren P: Agreed. MSI... Ugh, from a user's perspective. I hate when I can't uninstall something in Safe Mode because it *needs a service running which doesn't work in Safe Mode*. And only one [un]installer can run at once. And it takes forever to "gather require information" - ie, do what it should be doing. Gah. </rant>

Comment: Just yesterday I had an issue where WIndows Update failed because DCOM Service was down.   Because MSI needs DCOM. Well, duh, eh?  Because what I think of when I do installation is REMOTE PROCEDURE CALLS and distributed COM.  Haha.   I hate MSI.

Comment: +1 for Inno Setup which is probably the best install system! Also now it has native expert for Delphi (http://www.rad-installer.com) so you can use it directly from IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at the **Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)**.

The compilation of NSIS installer scripts can be integrated in your build system.

(You can even cross-compile your Windows installer on Linux, BSD or Mac OS X.)

Find out more at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/.

With NSIS you can build .exe installers (think setup.exe).

In case you want to build MSI packages, take a look at the **Windows Installer XML (WiX)** toolset.

More on this here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: NSIS has now native expert for Delphi (http:www.rad-installer.com) so you can use it directly from IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I work on a desktop application built in Delphi and we use the Wise Installation Studio to build our installers. It seems to be robust enough to handle what you need, including the ability to create MSI packages. However, it isn't a free product.

http://www.wise.com/Wise/Products/Installations/WiseInstallationStudio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Installaware would be my recommendation

http://installaware.com/

Comment: I think Delphi itself uses Installaware.  However it's a "heavy" weight system compared to "light" weight systems like Inno.  For some people, light will be preferred, and for some, the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DeployMaster](http://www.deploymaster.com) from Just Great Software since many years and am very happy with it.
It can be integrated in your build process.
Not free, but very reasonably priced.