# Problem to get Administrator right for program?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I searched and found how to gain Administrator access level for my program ([This Link](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/delphi-vista-registry-run-on-startup.htm), [This Link](http://www.lnssoftware.ca/blog/?p=113), [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx) and many other similar links), i did instructions step by step and think with no mistake, i checked every step for several times. 
After all when i finish the steps and want to compile my program, I receive this error:
"unable to create process: the application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. ..."
[image]

Where is my problem? Thank you.

---

Sorry for my delay, This is the manifest code i put beside my app (actually i copied and pasted it and just changed the "app.exe" name):

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED, THIS IS THE CORRECTED AND WORKING MANIFEST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.1.1.1"
   processorArchitecture="X86"
   name="MyApp.exe"
   type="win32"/>
  <description>elevate execution level</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
   <requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
   </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
  </trustInfo>
 </assembly>
```

**THANKS EVERY ONE HELPED ME TO CORRECT IT!**

Comment: You need to show your code. Without it, we're just guessing. Posting your manifest file or resource would be helpful, also; that's usually what "side-by-side configuration" is referencing.

Comment: Also please get this "more information" from `sxstrace.exe` tool - here is how: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx

Comment: @Ken, manifest code included in question.

Comment: Wait... The manifest looks fine, but then I re-read your question. "i finish the steps and want to **compile** my program" - are you saying the error happens in the IDE when you're trying to **compile**?

Comment: @Ken - The manifest is still wrong, it has been corrected only partly. Look at the value for 'manifestVersion' at the second line for instance, it's missing the closing double quote.

Comment: @Ken, error is not an IDE error, this error occurs when program is going to execute, when i want to run program outside Delphi IDE and directly from its place, this will happen again! but when i remove changes and recompile, everything is fine. @Sertac, manifest is re corrected and problem still exists....!

Comment: the manifest is still wrong for crying out loud!! Look for the missing terminating quotes!

Comment: @David, @Sertac- Thank you, it finally worked and dont cry anymore! But 2 more questions: 1) my program will write himself into registry "Run" key for run at startup, but after including manifest dont come up after windows start, does it related or i have to look for other problem? Registry is still writing correct but program dont start! 2) can i by any chance make any change to my program or windows configuration to dont ask for admin privilege every time and ask just once?

Comment: if you want to do admin tasks once in the first time your program runs then the correct solution is to do it in the installer and leave the program out of it. I think your deployment strategy is flawed.

Comment: i think this way too! it really flawed. Which installer you offer to use? i have no limit to order that, company will pay for it! i was planning to use InstallAware or InstallShield, should i change them or they work fine? after that have i remove included manifest and rebuild program? and after all what about first question?

Comment: your installer will do everything that needs admin rights and your program should not ever run elevated. That's the normal approach. I couldn't recommend an install program.

Comment: @Armin - There are some questions here involving installer alternatives, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561062/is-installshield-the-only-way-to-go-for-delphi-installations), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267255/delphi-installers-and-windows-7) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220499/installing-programs).. The two questions in the comment, you can ask on SO ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for `]` in the manifest and replace them with `">`

Comment: Code changed as you said, but problem still exists! its really bothering me......

Comment: @Armin - You haven't added the closing quotations ("), you've only corrected the brackets. Please take a closer look at the answer again.

Comment: Damn copy and paste! I had the same problem (copied the manifest file from the same web page) and went through the same mistakes (first fix the brackets, THEN fix the quotes...).

Answer (score 0):

Attention to the publickeytoken line, it must be in the manifest information. After that, Go to project/build...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
       version="6.0.0.0"
       publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
       ...
```